# How can I convert a sheet to a string? Or do I even need to?

Tags: python, excel, save, xlrd, xlwt

I'm having a problem taking an xlrd document and placing it into an xlwt file to be saved. I keep getting the error:

```
decode() argument 1 must be string, not Sheet
```

How can I change a Sheet back into a string? here is my code:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("Workbook1.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_name("worksheet")
wbk = xlwt.Workbook(sh)
sheet = wbk.add_sheet("sheet1")
```

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback. All those lines are there for a reason, which is to help debug. As it is, we don't even know what's calling `decode`.

Comment: Have you tried to look into documentations on these methods and objects at all?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use xlutils to bridge the two. That way your code will become:

```
import xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

read_book = xlrd.open_workbook("Workbook1.xlsx")
write_book = xlutils.copy(read_book)
write_sheet = write_book.add_sheet("sheet1")
```